PHP Mail to Googlemail. SPF only
i want to send mails via php to googlemail. I created a SPF txt dns record. Do i still need DKIM & DMARC?
No mails reach googlemail at the moment. I checked if the spf was active with https://www.nslookup.io/
Is it not gonna work without DKIM & DMARC? I don't need/want a company account in google.


This almost certainly has nothing to do with PHP, and everything to do with your mailserver setup. Unless of course you're doing something silly in the PHP code  like faking emails from other providers using a From address which doesn't match your mailserver's domain. We don't know, since there's no code sample, and no debugging/log info from your mailserver in your post, which might allude to why mail isn't being sent (or, perhaps, isn't being received - these are 2 different things). But yeah DKIM and DMARC are a good idea, no matter who you're sending email to.

I don't need/want a company account in google...not sure why that would be relevant? You said you're only sending emails to (presumably other people's) googlemail addresses. It's unclear how you think your own google account would help with that.

I need a google account for the company for DMARC. Because i need to access the admin console.
Do i need DKIM and DMARC for emails to reach googlemail if i already have a spf? That's all i want to know.

If you're using your company's account that's hosted by gmail/gsuite, then you're going to have to talk to whomever has access to the admin console to get the DKIM key.  You don't need that access for DMARC, since that's just a policy.

huh? DMARC is just a policy standard. It's not a google product. You should be able to configure it on your own mailserver. If your mailserver is run by google of course, then maybe that's a different matter. It's unclear what the full scenario is, due to lack of details in your post.

And you don't need DKIM or DMARC to email to send to Google accounts, but it certainly does help.

@aynber there are some on the internet who disagree. And I've experienced a problem with mails to googlemail accounts being rejected myself, a few months ago when they updated their policy. Setting those up solved the problem. There's some disagreement online whether it only applies to "bulk senders" but from personal experience I'd say it was sensible to enable them.

Thanks @aynber thats all i wanted to know. I just want to be able to send mails to google mail via php. Nothing more. So the spf is probably not "fully" active yet maybe and i have to wait. Thanks for the answer!

@Jules I would say you need to have them. And I wouldn't say that would require you to have a google account yourself, unless the mailserver you're sending via from your PHP code is somehow managed under google services.

@ADyson Does google accept mails where the server fails the spf check but not the DMARC authentication?
No nothing of the sort, the mail server is not managed by google.

Does google accept mails where the server fails the spf check but not the DMARC authentication...not sure, I've never tried it. You could ask the internet if anyone has ever tried or experienced that.

hmm Google says i need a google account to create the dmarc entry that i can paste as a txt dns record on my server
https://support.google.com/a/answer/180504?hl=en&ref_topic=2752442&sjid=15679694600533292474-EU

No nothing of the sort, the mail server is not managed by google...in that case it's hard to imagine why you think you need a google company account to sort out your DMARC. I have DMARC on a server I manage, it can send to google, no google account of my own was required. Are you sure you've read that correctly? Can you provide a link to the source of that information?

Because if the DMARC authentication does not help if spf fails, why should i need it then?

The idea is to have all the systems working, before the mail would be considered valid. DMARC builds on top of SPF and DKIM, to add extra validation. It's not a replacement.

Is the domain you're sending from a gmail account, a domain whose email is hosted by google, or not related to Google at all?

@aynber it is not related to google in any way.

@ADyson all this just to be able to send to googlemail....

@Jules so you just see this as meaningless beauracracy, then? Is that what you're saying? You don't think that having the ability to do things like validate that the sender of an email is likely to be the real, authorised sender is a valuable thing? Perhaps you don't know the torrid history of email's battles with spam, spoofing and so on. These tools are hugely valuable to system administrators, and those who try to prevent abuse of the global email systems and protocols (which for too long were extremely open, and permissive, and easy to mis-use)

There are a lot of good reasons why mail providers are introducing these standards and policies...and let me assure you it isn't because they enjoy making your life pointlessly difficult. The major providers may have gone first but this stuff will be a requirement everywhere in the foreseeable future.

Okay, if it's not related to Google in any way, then you don't need access to a Google admin account. A google admin account is only if your domain's email is being hosted by Google. https://dmarcian.com/create-a-dkim-record/ explains how to create a DKIM record

@ADyson I'm saying why we need ALL that. spf should be enough shouldn't it? A DNS Record sould be enough. Why the 2 extra things.

Because evidently, SPF wasn't enough. If it was, we wouldn't be bothering. If you do some reading online, you can learn what the differences are, and what the different schemes are validating - then you'll be able to see why they are all useful. I'll say again - nobody is doing this for fun or to annoy you. If it wasn't necessary, it wouldn't be  happening - it's an additional overhead for everybody.

https://www.cloudflare.com/en-gb/learning/email-security/dmarc-dkim-spf/

https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/16gvtdj/can_someone_explain_dmarc_spf_and_dkim_to_me_like/

https://www.mimecast.com/content/dkim-spf-dmarc-explained/

Google has a lot of published guidance on this topic:
Requirements for all senders

Starting February 1, 2024, all email senders who send email to Gmail accounts must meet the requirements in this section.
Important: If you send more than 5,000 messages per day to Gmail
accounts, follow the Requirements for sending 5,000 or more messages
per day.

Set up SPF or DKIM email authentication for your sending domains.
Ensure that sending domains or IPs have valid forward and reverse DNS
records, also referred to as PTR records.
Use a TLS
connection for transmitting email.
Keep spam
rates reported in Postmaster Tools below 0.3%.
Format messages according to the Internet Message Format
standard, RFC 5322.
Don’t impersonate Gmail From: headers. Gmail will
begin using a DMARC quarantine enforcement policy, and impersonating
Gmail From: headers might impact your email delivery.
If you manage a
forwarding service, including mailing lists or inbound gateways, add
ARC headers to outgoing email. ARC headers indicate the message was
forwarded and identify you as the forwarder. Mailing list senders
should also add a List-id: header, which specifies the mailing list,
to outgoing messages.


Requirements for sending 5,000 or more messages per day

Starting February 1, 2024, email senders who send more than 5,000 messages per day to Gmail accounts must meet the requirements in this section.

Set up SPF and DKIM email authentication for your domain.
Ensure that sending domains or IPs have valid forward and reverse DNS records, also referred to as PTR records.
Use a TLS connection for transmitting email.
Keep spam rates reported in Postmaster Tools below 0.30%. Learn more about spam rates
Format messages according to the Internet Message Format standard, RFC 5322.
Don’t impersonate Gmail From: headers. Gmail will begin using a DMARC quarantine enforcement policy, and impersonating Gmail From:
headers might impact your email delivery.
If you manage a forwarding service, including mailing lists or inbound gateways, add ARC headers to outgoing email. ARC headers
indicate the message was forwarded and identify you as the forwarder.
Mailing list senders should also add a List-id: header, which
specifies the mailing list, to outgoing messages.
Set up DMARC email authentication for your sending domain. Your DMARC enforcement policy can be set to none.
For direct mail, the domain in the sender's From: header must be aligned with either the SPF domain or the DKIM domain. This is
required to pass DMARC alignment.
Marketing messages and subscribed messages must support one-click unsubscribe, and include a clearly visible unsubscribe link in the
message body.


Additionally:

To verify messages are authenticated, Google performs checks on
messages sent to Gmail accounts. To improve email delivery, we
recommend that you always set up SPF, DKIM, and DMARC for your
domains. Make sure you're meeting the minimum authentication
requirements described on this page. Messages that aren’t
authenticated with these methods might be marked as spam or rejected
with a 5.7.26 error.
If you use an email service provider, verify that they authenticate
your domain’s email with SPF and DKIM.

Source (and more detail on other configuration requirements): https://support.google.com/a/answer/81126?visit_id=638513785227520464-3322085938&rd=1 (as at 2024-05-15)
